# How to dynamically specify type in TypeScript generics?

Tags: typescript, mixins, typescript-generics

How I should modify generic type parameter `U` of `areaCalculator` argument of `WithArea` function for it to extend the base class of current `MixinFactory` instance?

```js
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface IArea {
    readonly area: number;
}

class MixinFactory<T extends Constructor<Shape>> {
    constructor(public Superclass: T) {}

    WithArea(areaCalculator: <U extends Shape & IArea>(ctx: U) => number) {
        return new MixinFactory<T & Constructor<IArea>>(class extends this.Superclass implements IArea {
            get area(): number {
                return areaCalculator(this);
            }
        })
    }
}

class Shape {}

class RectRaw extends Shape {
    constructor(
        public x: number,
        public y: number,
        public w: number,
        public h: number) {
            super();
        }
}

const Rect = new MixinFactory(RectRaw).WithArea(ctx => {
    return ctx.w * ctx.h;
}).Superclass;

const rect = new Rect(10, 10, 20, 20);

console.log(rect.area);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: It took me a while to understand your code, pretty complicated )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `areaCalculator` function doesn't need to be generic; there is no need for an additional type parameter `U`, and this type parameter is not exposed by the method `get area(): number`.

The `areaCalculator` function only needs to be defined as accepting whatever object the constructor type `T` returns, so with the `InstanceType` helper, we can extract that and use it directly in the type annotation:

```
class MixinFactory<T extends Constructor<Shape>> {
    constructor(public Superclass: T) {}

    WithArea(areaCalculator: (ctx: InstanceType<T> & IArea) => number) {
        return new MixinFactory<T & Constructor<IArea>>(class extends this.Superclass implements IArea {
            get area(): number {
                return areaCalculator(this as InstanceType<T> & IArea);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Note that a type assertion `this as InstanceType<T> & IArea` is needed because Typescript isn't able to figure out that if a class extends `this.Superclass` of type `T` then its instances must have type `InstanceType<T>`.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQDcAKEkBLBMAioAZk0zQAkgEFUEJlADekqMag6mAE0QAbENzNcE6ALYAjRVIC+0zFaZIkUACyMgAecgBiqjioIIRQECEKCOYB8MhoWNF4AMoAFkyQRCSGJlCYiCgY2Li0YOguVjKYUNnokKg+fpxQBCL6XkYmAOoywLnaurQsujBMVpjovtFctNghXOrpPGoE4BCEJABkUFpmIqQkjq6KfYOlxjrA6KgIFNRBoRFRuLEEUMdpSqZXB4U66IqrXz+eKJCDJAJjGRIeitdqdaEyJxgKwQJxw4ABMF6Er3UmsCDAOyTIQOZxuVAGO6k5mPZ6vaZMWbzRZMaK0REBPwnLYIHZ7A7-E4TJhCKTM+5eeUeIRMrwDdEBPIFaD9bxQgIAJQg2ANTBoCSSKRa+UgjNK5XSVT5TNKdQaTSg6wodMUABoXSY3Y1miBaddUP75UGPVQw-TI8zo81cnGbnb5SYkG1FLRZQHjGrvBVKUbsGQ3jRgmEEJFqjFaKXgKaqEJ6CMxtLVsAQqJ0w8KWyyt36DQAFRDkL0XKeVuoxQaqSSB0oUzGynkSg0Ru0ACMAAZfVB94eAEwHqBnvNLipwHH0KxwVi0HTYegc2VAA)

Comment: This is correct.  FYI there is a built-in utility type InstanceType<T> which is (I think) the same as your ConstructorReturnType<T>.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Thanks for pointing that out, I've improved the answer.

Comment: In your answer, `ctx` also has access to the whole inheritance chain, it's a nice bonus. Thank you!